# How to dynamically go back after changing a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I changed the **getitem** special method to make implementation of perl's autovivification feature with python dictionary, like this:

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
        """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""

        def __getitem__(self, item):

                try:
                        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)

                except KeyError:
                        value = self[item] = type(self)()
                        return value
```

This is very useful, but now I do not find the way to go back to the dictionary original class for the created object. Firstly, is it possible ?

Comment: "I do not find the way to go back to the dictionary original class for the created object" please elaborate, I don't understand.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like you want a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: if I do a=dict() then a['tutu']['toutou']=3 I raise the error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> KeyError: 'tutu'. If now I do a=AutoVivification() then a['tutu']['toutou']=3 is working. BUT, now if I want to make my "a" object like a normal dictionary, what can I do ?

Comment: why do you need to go back to a regular dictionary? you would need to recursively go through each element and do something like `sub_dict[key] = dict(sub_dict[key])` for each `AutoVivification` object in the structure.

Comment: I would like to go back AFTER the creation of the dictionary to protect him. Because all was working well before I seen that for example if I do a['nana']['nana'].items() the {'nana': {'nana': {}} is created, while I just want test for but not change the dictionary ...

Comment: Why don't you add a method which returns the underlying dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that the feature can be turned off:

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.vivify = True
        self.root = self

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            if not self.root.vivify:
                raise
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            value.root = self.root
            return value

    def unvivify(self):
        self.vivify = False
```

Usage:

```
a = AutoVivification()
a['b']['c'] = 3
print(a)
a.unvivify()
print(a['b']['d'])
```

Output:

```
{'b': {'c': 3}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexhall/Dropbox/python/books/sandbox/sandbox.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(a['b']['d'])
  File "/Users/alexhall/Dropbox/python/books/sandbox/sandbox.py", line 9, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
KeyError: 'd'
```

Comment: This looks very nice, Alex Hall ! I will try it ASAP (it's currently  bed time where I am ) !

Comment: I am playing with your proposition. I have just a first remark. With python 2.x the code raise an error: TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given). So, for python 2.x I propose this little change : super(AutoVivification, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) Do you validate it ?

Comment: A second thing :-) I use the dic of dic as a little database like and I have already lot of data in the old fashioned dic of dic (with the AutoVivification class discribed in my first post). If I creates a new dic of dic with the AutoVivification class you proposed it will be OK. But for the old one ? I have not yet played with, but have you an idea to do it ?

Comment: Ok I just finish to play with !!!! And thank you Alex Hall, all is perfect, it is exactly what I looked for :-) Just 3 minor things:

Comment: 1/ I validates the need of changing  super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) by super(AutoVivification, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) for python 2.x (no need to change with python 3.x).

Comment: 2/ I added one other method : def revivify(self): self.vivify = True to give the possibility to switch as we want between vivification and not.

Comment: 3/ Concerning the problem to upgrade dic of dic with old AutoVivification (my first post), I used a quick and dirty way by adding the line  self.root = self in the revivify() method. Then I removed this line in the method after a first pass !. All seems working well . Thank you again @Alex Hall, all the best !